# Typescript library for Node as hybrid package in NPM

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6, commonjs

How to properly configure **typescript** `tsconfig.json` and **npm** `package.json` to create a **hybrid npm package**?

I mostly followed [this article](https://2ality.com/2019/10/hybrid-npm-packages.html) (but I also tried other methods)

This is the alpha version of my library [gomshal on github](https://github.com/atiris/gomshal). This last state that I describe here is in [the branch hybrid-2.3](https://github.com/atiris/gomshal/tree/hybrid-2.3). I wanted to use **ESM as a basic import** and a **CommonJS as option**. This is described in [chapter 2.3 of the article](https://2ality.com/2019/10/hybrid-npm-packages.html#option-3%3A-bare-import-esm%2C-deep-import-commonjs-with-backward-compatibility). My lib files [exports](https://github.com/atiris/gomshal/tree/hybrid-2.3/src/lib) through `index.ts` class Gomshal, enums and interfaces.

**Project structure**

My sources are in `"./src/lib"`. I have two tsconfig.json files: `tsconfig.esm.json` and `tsconfig.cjs.json`. Both includes same `"./src/lib/**/*.ts"` files as a source. Differecnes are in compilerOptions:

```
// tsconfig.cjs.json for CommonJS
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./build/lib/cjs",
  "target": "ES5",
  "module": "CommonJS",
  ...
}

// tsconfig.esm.json for ES6 module
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build/lib/esm",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "ES2015",
  ...
}
```

Besides, I also have a file `package.json` specific for commonjs with content: `{ "type": "commonjs" }`. Important keys from my root package.json are:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./build/lib/esm/index.js",
  "module": "./build/lib/esm/index.js",
  "typings": "./build/lib/esm/index.d.ts",
  "files": [ "build/lib/**/*" ],
  "exports": {
    "./esm": "./build/lib/esm/index.js",
    "./cjs": "./build/lib/cjs/index.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

So everything here is targeting to **ES6 module by default**. After compilation (`tsc -p tsconfig.esm.json` and `tsc -p tsconfig.cjs.json`) two folders are created in the build directory (`build/lib/cjs` and `build/lib/esm`). Package json file from `src/cjs` is coppied to `build/lib/cjs` and everything looks ready to publish. Now when I try `npm pack` with this settings, copy generated tgz file and `npm install` into demo project (part of `package.json`: `"type": "module", "dependencies": {"gomshal": "file:gomshal-1.4.2.tgz"}`), minimal demo `index.js`:

```js
import { Gomshal } from 'gomshal';
gomshal = new Gomshal();
```

The error ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND is returned:

```
node .\index.js
(node:23404) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:58
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^

Error: Cannot find module D:\Workspace\gomshal\npmtest\node_modules\gomshal\build\lib\esm\gomshal imported from D:\Workspace\gomshal\npmtest\node_modules\gomshal\build\lib\esm\index.js
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:58:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:188:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

I tried other variants in root package.json (`"main"` targeting to cjs and `"module"` targeting esm compiled code and other combinations in `"exports"` key) but in this case I am probably closest to the hybrid package.  My node version is 13.8.0, npm 6.13.6, tsc version 3.8.3.

However, **I still can't configure my npm package** to make the named ESM import `import { Gomshal } from 'gomshal';` usable without error. What did i miss?